# How to "statify" a line so that it is not interactive?

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart that has one spline. Whenever I approach this line, it becomes "active" and displays its points.

I would like to make it non-interactive (static) - so that just the line is displayed and otherwise not selectable. I had a look at the [available properties](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.spline) for the `spline` but none seem to match.

Is such behaviour possible? Or does each element have to be interactive in Highcharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `enableMouseTracking` property, which needs to be disabled in your case.

```
  series: [{
    type: 'spline',
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    ...
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1yb3L7an/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.spline.enableMouseTracking